# JSON Parsing dataTaskWithUrl returns 0 bytes of data

Tags: json, swift, nsurlsessiondatatask

Hi I'm trying to retrieve data from url. So I'm using dataTask with url.

THe response received is showing as 0 bytes but the I print it shown around 46171 bytes of data in upperbound...please find below screen shot. Because of this im not able to parse json

PLease advice what needs to be done in this case

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the results to do anything useful, then you need to implement the `completionHandler`.

Also, if you want to access the `URL` (from the `urlRequest`) and obtain the results of a `GET` request, then you need to add `task.resume()`.

I hope the following example helps:

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:{ (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
    if let response = response {
        print(response)
    }
    if let error = error { 
        print(error)
    }   
}) 
    task.resume()
```